# Jenkins job DSL: groovy job change PATH

Tags: groovy, path, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm writing Jenkins job using job DSL. It looks like:

```
job(jobName) {
  description("This is my Jenkins job.")
  steps {
    // Executing some shell here.
  }
  scm {
    // Checking out some branch from Git.
  }
  triggers {
    bitbucketPush()
    scm ''
  }
}
```

It works fine, but for some reason, executing my shell script it fails with an errors:

`/usr/lib/git-core/git-pull: 83: /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: sed: not found
basename: write error: Broken pipe
/usr/lib/git-core/git-pull: 299: /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: uname: not found`

etc.

As far as I understand, the issue is with `PATH` variable. When I'm fixing  it in Jenkins from UI (in `Configure` section) it works fine. (adding something like this: `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`
As I'm creating a lot of job, it would great to fix this `PATH` during creation process in my DSL scripts.

How it may be added into my DSL?

Comment: Which job DSL command do you use for executing the shell? Can you expand the part of your code in the `steps` block?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni, I'm executing some custom script which is doing some `gitcheckout`, `git pull`, `git merge` commands, etc.

Comment: What is the output of `out.println($PATH)` and `out.println('$PATH')` at the tie you run your seed job?

Comment: @thiagowfx,  print as string returns `$PATH`. Print with variable return an error:
`ERROR: (script, line 1119) No such property: $PATH for class: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext`

Comment: So, I've decided this issue outside of Job DSL. I've added `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` into my `PATH` variable in my script from `steps` section.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not related to Job DSL. Try to configure the job manually and fix all problems. Then translate you configuration to Job DSL.

In this case there is something wrong with the environment on you build agent, e.g. git is not installed properly.

Comment: So, I've added `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin` into `PATH` variable on UI, but how to translate this to Job DSL?